# How to stop Bootstrap 3.1.1 from shift content left when scroll bar appears?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and when I have a page that requires a vertical scroll bar due to a lot of content, Bootstrap shifts the html body over -15px to made room for the vertical scroll bar.  This was a big issue for Bootstrap modals but it was fixed in 3.0.1 I believe.

Any ideas, tricks, or hacks to avoid this problem?

Comment: Show some code please???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Stop My Web Content From Shifting Left When The Vertical Scrollbar Appears? Roll-Up of Advice 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524214/how-do-i-stop-my-web-content-from-shifting-left-when-the-vertical-scrollbar-appe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the scroll-bar always visible, so there is no visual jump when going from long pages and back.

CSS:

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```